# Зависание основного потока

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность

На WPF форме есть элемент **TextBox txt**. Создаётся фоновый поток, который в цикле выполняет некоторые вычисления для **float value**. По окончанию каждого вычисления, происходит вызов:
**Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {txt.Text = value.ToString();}));**
Возможно ли такое, что основной поток зависает, а фоновый продолжает выполняться и добавлять в очередь основного потока **txt.Text = value**. В следствии чего, программа начинает потреблять всю свободную память и в конце концов крашит систему.

Comment: Если вы в цикле вызовите `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {txt.Text = value.ToString();}));`  100500 раз подряд, то вы да, можете перегрузить основной поток. Контроллируйте сколько раз вы в цикле и с какой частотой пытаетесь обновить UI

Comment: Не подскажите, как это обычно делают? Как проверить, выполнена ли команда основным потоком или нет? И можно ли вообще из фонового потока проверить не завис ли основной? Это возможно?

Comment: Как обычно делают что? вы ж кода не показали никакого. Проверить состояние отправленной операции можно, смотрите что этот метод `BeginInvoke` возвращает. Проверить, не завис ли основной поток тоже можно, достаточно отправить в него задачу и замерить, как долго она выполняетя

Comment: Благодарю. Постараюсь разобраться с DispatcherOperation